# How to prefix Plus sign "+" before the number if the value is negative in Google Sheets or MS Excel?

Tags: excel, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I am trying to add/prefix a plus sign "+" if the value is negative. e.g. **+10**

I have sheet where some bill payments are made and sometimes they overpay. So, the Balance column should reflect like +(over paid value).

I tried with `=CONCATENATE` but this does not help. It comes as **+-10**

```
=IF(C2<0,CONCATENATE("+",C2),"")
```

[image]

Comment: note that appending + will result in conversion of format so instead of numeric value you will have a text string. therefore use *-1

Answer (score 35):

You can try going to `Format > Number > More formats > Custom number format` and inserting the following expression: `+0;-0;0`

This will cause negative values to be show with a `+` sign, and positive ones to be shown with a `-` sign. The value that it holds, however, will still be the original one (as a number).

See [docs](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/56470?visit_id=637978166806391180-4154371931&p=drive_custom_numbers&rd=1#zippy=%2Ccustom-number-formatting) (code formatting added):

> When creating a custom format, note that the formatting can consist of up to 4 parts separated by semicolons: `positive;negative;zero;non-numeric`.

Comment: I had to use `+0;-0;0` or it would put a `-` in front of positive numbers.

Answer (score 1):

all you need is this:

```
=IF(A2-B2<0, A2-B2*-1, )
```

[image]

then Arrayformula would be:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A-B2:B<0, A2:A-B2:B*-1, ))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
=if(C2<0, "+" & ABS(C2),  C2)
```

Or

```
=If(C2<0,"+","")&ABS(C2)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure that all cells will have numbers, then you may format cells to have "Number" rather than "General". Then, rewrite your condition as follows: `=IF(C2<0,CONCATENATE("+", -1 * C2),"")`.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(C2,"-","+")
```

Comment: thanks. it actually works but only visually. The value ceases to be a number and hence it does not count when added with another number.

Answer (score -1):

Try this formula:

```
=IF(C2<0,"+","")&C2
```